# '(String, AnyObject)' is not convertible to '[String : AnyObject]'

Tags: swift

```
// response is of type AnyObject!
let responseDic = response as [String : AnyObject]
let userDic = responseDic["user"] as [String : AnyObject]
```

However, on the last line, I get the error:

```
'(String, AnyObject)' is not convertible to '[String : AnyObject]'
```

So I'm guessing looking up a key in a dictionary returns an optional value, so then I tried:

```
let userDic = responseDic["user"]? as [String : AnyObject]
```

But I get:

```
'String' is not convertible to 'DictionaryIndex<String, AnyObject>'
```

What's the proper way to get this to work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use an exclamation point instead to unwrap the optional:

```
var response: AnyObject! = ["user" : [String : AnyObject]()]
let responseDic = response as [String : AnyObject]
let userDic: [String : AnyObject] = responseDic["user"]! as [String : AnyObject]
```

And if you want to make sure there is a non-nil value for the key 'user' and it is a [String : AnyObject] you can use an if let:

```
if let user: AnyObject = responseDic["user"] {
    if let userDic = user as? [String : AnyObject]{
        //do stuff with userDic
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this cause an exception is `responseDic["user"]` is nil? What's the safe way to do it?

Comment: It will. I added another snippet

Comment: Is there a shorter way to do the second way you've added?

Comment: you may be able to combine them into one line, although I don't think I was able to. I can't test that right now though